# Range extension for new blu ray

Tags: wireless-networking, ethernet, range, extension

My man cave in in my shop ( metal building) 200' from the house. I have a RG6 line from the splitter to the TV and a CAT5 line from the router ( Belkin N600) to my computer. WiFi does not seem to work, possibly the distance and the metal building). The other ports on the router go to my VOIP and 2 computers on other 200' runs. An Amped SR10000 midway seems to allow connection for the Apple folks but not the older pc's.
PROBLEM How do I add a smart blue ray player to the man cave to get Amazon prime ? I do not have an extra router port to add another CAT cable and the PC won't connect wirelessly.
can I add another router in the man cave using the ethernet cable?

Answer (score 1):

Purchase a network switch (5 ports is probably plenty) and place it in the "man cave."  Connect the CAT5 cable you currently have running out there to one port of the switch, then get a couple new CAT5 cables to connect your other devices to the switch.

Comment: +1 - and also, OP _could_ purchase another router since most have a built-in switch, but would then require some more careful configuration to put it into bridge mode.